# Divider isn't drawn. How to inflate the Drawing-Area?

Tags: c#, listview, graphics, drawing, columnheader

I'm drawing ColumnHeaders in a Winforms-ListView in C#.
My Problem is that the last Divider/Separator of the Columns (the One after the last Column) isn't drawn. Is the Drawing-Area too small or is it another Problem? How could I fix this?

```
protected void list_DrawColumnHeader( object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e ) {
  var state = e.State == ListViewItemStates.Selected ?
      VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Hot : VisualStyleElement.Header.Item.Normal;
  VisualStyleRenderer itemRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer( state );
  Rectangle r = e.Bounds;
  r.X += 1;
  itemRenderer.DrawBackground( e.Graphics, r );
...
```

Comment: you add 1 to the left, so it is probably overdrawn. maybe you should also make the width 1 less?

Comment: I add 1 to X so it lines up with the GridLines. The Divider is drawn if I don't move it by One Pixel but of course it also doesn't line up in that case, which is why i draw it in the first place. So it seems like the area it draws on isn't wide enough for the last divider with the offset. Which width should I change?

Comment: This is a bug in Windows itself, I see it on Win10.  Not much you can do about it, you can't draw the dividers nor the gridlines yourself.  Setting GridLines = False is the only practical workaround I can think of, beyond calling Microsoft Support.